# I have some errors using netbeans, I am trying using files

Tags: java, file-io

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt")));
```

But, ¿Where Do I have to save the text file? 
I have some errors like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: help.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

Comment: Try putting the file in `resources` folder, or in the same folder as the file itself.

Comment: I have tried but the errors are the same

Comment: Try giving the entire path name "c:\...\input.txt" on Windows or "<path>/input.txt" in *NIX